# How to migrate complete TFS 2012 code as well as history to VSTS in Azure

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-artifacts

Our project which is in TFS 2012 needs to be migrated to VSTS in azure. 
Belew are the complexities

- Size greater than 300 GB in SQL DB
- Domains are different of in premise and Azure
- Will developers able to check out during migration process.

As this is first time I am involved in such process I need thoughts, Links, Pros and Cons and process flow how to approach this migration.

Comment: If someone is going to vote something down, they should not be so cs as to not say why...

Answer (score 4):

When you decide to make the move from TFS into Team Services, you might start fresh with an empty account. Often, however, you will have existing code, work items, and other assets that you want to move. There are many approaches to doing this - some available now and some coming in the future. They vary in both the fidelity of the data transfer and the complexity of the process.

**Option 1: Copy the most important assets manually**

Here's the general process:

- Identify the most important assets that you need to migrate - typically source code, work items, or both. Other assets in TFS – build definitions, test plans, and so forth – are harder to manually migrate.
- Identify a good time to make the transition.
- Prepare your target Team Services accounts. Create the accounts and team projects that you need, provision users, and so on.
- Migrate your data.
- Consider making the source TFS deployments read-only.

**Option 2: Using public API-based tools for higher fidelity migration**

- The Team Foundation Server Integration Tools are freely available: [Visual Studio Gallery download for TFS Integration Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-integration-solutions).
- Various commercial options are available as well See [Migration and integration solutions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-integration-solutions).

**Option 3: High fidelity database migration:**

The TFS/Team Services product team is hard at work on a higher fidelity migration tool.

More information, check this article: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts

Comment: Cece - this tool was supposedly scheduled for Q2 so do you have any status? This tool is needed if you want folks to consider moving to VSTS.

Comment: the option 3 link does not show any status on the high fidelity migration tool. Can you give some status please given it is long overdue. Thanks.